# Difference between (n&1) and n&1

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I was trying to solve a [Counter Game](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w8/challenges/counter-game) problem:

"Louise and Richard play a game. They have a counter set to N. Louise gets the first turn and the turns alternate thereafter. In the game, they perform the following operations.

- If N is not a power of 2, they reduce the counter by the largest power of 2 less than N.
- If N is a power of 2, they reduce the counter by half of N.
- The resultant value is the new N which is again used for subsequent operations.

The game ends when the counter reduces to 1, i.e., N == 1, and the last person to make a valid move wins.

Given N, your task is to find the winner of the game."

To solve the question, [I implemented](http://ideone.com/RUVsEQ) bit manipulation, and [got accepted](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w8/challenges/counter-game/submissions/code/1919998):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    long long unsigned int n, tmp;
    int cnt, t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--) {
        scanf("%llu", &n), tmp=n;
        cnt=0;
        while(tmp) tmp&=tmp-1, cnt++;
        cnt--;
        while((n&1)==0) n>>=1, cnt++;
        if(cnt%2==0) printf("Richard\n");
        else printf("Louise\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, during the coding i coded `while(n&1==false)` instead of `while((n&1)==false)`, thus could not get desired result. Coding `while(!(n&1))` gave expected result, but that(`!a` instead of `a==false`) was bad practice due to some sources(I forgot them) I have read online. And I know the difference between `while(!n&1)` and `while(!(n&1))`, but I did not know `while(n&1==false)` and `while((n&1)==false)`. Learnt the latter was and is dissimilar, and may I ask the distinction, please?

Comment: What's the difference between `1+2*3` and `(1+2)*3`? It's the same problem here.

Comment: usage of `,` operator should be avoided

Comment: most compiler warn about the lack of parenthesis

Comment: `!a` is usually not considered a bad practice... It may be bad practice for integers in case 0 means "true"/"success" (like `strcmp`).

Comment: I don't agree that `!a` was bad practice. Quite the contrary, I would strongly prefer `!a` to `a==false`. Comparing a boolean (a) to a boolean (false) just to get a boolean that you had in the first place seems rather strange to me. The 'not' operator ! on the other hand has clear semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is considered by many a design mistake of C.

While it's natural that a `logical-and` operation should have lower precedence than equality comparison the same is much more questionable for `bitwise-and` because bitwise operations are naturally closer to math operations.

The same design error has been inherited by C++ for backward compatibility.

A good rule is always parenthesize bitwise operations to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the precedence of `==` is above the precedence of `&`.

Therefore `n&1==false` is interpreted as `n&(1==false)` **not** `(n&1)==false`, so you need the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

`==` has higher priority in C++ than `&` ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)).

Thus `while(n&1==false)` is treated as `while (n & (1 == false))` which actually is `while (n & 0)`.